# SSH with gpg-agent: order of keys

Tags: ssh, gnupg

I have GPG set up to talk to SSH (with `--enable-ssh-support`). I have two keys: say `0x1234` and `0xABCD`. Both keys have the following subkeys:

- a signing key
- an encryption key
- an authentication key

Therefore, I have two different public keys when I run `ssh-add -L` with `0x1234` first followed by `0xABCD` (I think this order is defined by whichever key was last added). It all works nicely.

I *need* two different keys because I have some servers that accept only one of the two keys. However, I also have servers that accept both keys (Github, for example). I would prefer to use `0xABCD` over `0x1234` even though both will be accepted. However, SSH will always choose the first accepted key, so `0x1234` is preferred over `0xABCD` all the time in such servers.

I imagine this has to be changed in the GPG side of things because it's `gpg-agent` that's returning the keys in this order.

Is there any way I can force the order of keys reported?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and edited `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` to reorder the entries.

```
# List of allowed ssh keys.  Only keys present in this file are used
# in the SSH protocol.  The ssh-add tool may add new entries to this
# file to enable them; you may also add them manually.  Comment
# lines, like this one, as well as empty lines are ignored.  Lines do
# have a certain length limit but this is not serious limitation as
# the format of the entries is fixed and checked by gpg-agent. A
# non-comment line starts with optional white spaces, followed by the
# keygrip of the key given as 40 hex digits, optionally followed by a
# caching TTL in seconds, and another optional field for arbitrary
# flags.   Prepend the keygrip with an '!' mark to disable it.

# Ed25519 key added on: 2019-01-01 07:08:09
# Fingerprints:  MD5:93:75:54:e3:58:91:6c:7e:25:8f:f4:dd:98:81:8d:1a
#                SHA256:RP+Mcdf4WsZeBkfrdumZmUBlt7bPSkENyVgFpxs276o
B0651F46AEC857C8C842231E74C71A03622DBCD1 0
# ... more entries
```

Keys are used in the order they appear in this file.  You can use `ssh-add -l` to show the sha256 hashes for the keys you were looking at via `ssh-add -L`.

Comment: Unfortunately order of keys in `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` did not help me (using Debian Bullseye `gpg-agent 2.2.27-2+deb11u2`). The order of offered keys was still the same - my `~/.ssh/id_rsa` was still offered before my smartkey everytime. Removing the `id_rsa` key from the list (either by commenting it out with `#` or by prepending `!` as comments advise) however did at least allow that gpg-agent skip the key (which was good enough for me, as ssh will fallback to try to read ~/.ssh/id_rsa directly if no key offered by agent is accept)

Comment: _keygrips_ of keys that gpg-agent knows about can be listed (i.e. which would be shown by `ssh-add -l`) can be listed with `gpg-connect-agent 'KEYINFO --ssh-list --ssh-fpr=sha256' /bye`